# iPhone 11 pro didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios13

I had developed an application in Xcode 10. Now I am running my app in Xcode 11.1.

The app works as expected in all devices but iPhone 11 Pro. For iPhone 11 Pro, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is not called neither `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is called.

Comment: Please provide **minimal** code that focuses on the specific problem so people can understand where this comes from. As of now, this is not very helpful for other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting the most annoying 2h, here are the steps to fix the issue:

1. Turn off wifi
2. Enable Cellural Data